# Client object model with Claims Enabled Site

Tags: sharepoint-2010, claims-based-identity

How do you connect to a SharePoint site using client object model, if site is claims enabled, and if it is using a third party identity provider without encapsulating httpcontext and trying to get a cookie?

In browser environment, I got SP site, redirected to third party STS, put in credentials, redirected back to SP STS, and then to the site.

In client object model, if this is a console app, I go to third party STS, get a saml1.1 or saml 2.0 token, and do that?

Answer (score 0):

Steve published a sample of how to authenticate against Claims by using ClientOM on his blog http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/06/04/using-the-client-object-model-with-a-claims-based-auth-site-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

I think this should work for your situation too